# Android Studio PATH Environment, running a custom script in PATH

Tags: android, bash, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to add a custom task to my Android gradle build process.

```
task doSomethingCustom(type: Exec) {
     println 'Do Something Custom'
     commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'find ./app/res | grep res_name | xargs -I % custom_script_in_path %'
}

[...]

preBuild.dependsOn doSomethingCustom
```

I would like to run this custom script "custom_script_in_path" that is in the $PATH of all building machines as part of the build process.  This works fine from the command line, and I can open the resulting app and see the modified behavior.

However, when I run this within the Android Studio environment, it errors out giving me the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':android_app:doSomethingCustom'.
> Process 'command 'bash'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

*UPDATE*

1. Verified that the path seen by AndroidStudio is:

```
path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

2. I also tried:

```
commandLine 'sh', '-c', 'command...'
```

To no success.

3. I'm working on

MacOSX: 10.11.6

AndroidStudio: 2.1.3

How can I modify the $PATH seen by AndroidStudio?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: MacOSX 10.11.6 - I updated the question with additional information.

Comment: Why not just `xargs -I % /path/to/custom_script_in_path %`?

Comment: The path will be different across various developers' machines.  The Path will be different also depending on which branch and workspace I happen to be working in at the time.

Comment: If your question is specifically "How can I modify the $PATH...", could you just add `environment "PATH", "myCustomDesignedPathToMyCommand"` into your `task doSomethingCustom {...` definition?