# Is there a $PATH environment variable for Gradle commands within Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a custom build script that runs an npm command. The command works on my command line, so its installed. But it doesnt run in Android Studio (Chipmunk 2021.2.1). Oddly, it used to run a couple weeks ago. Nothing has changed that I know of. The error is:

```
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'npm'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

It looks like it cant find npm anymore because whatever AS is using as an environment PATH is out of sync with the system path (MacOS 12.4 zsh). How can I find and set the PATH Android Studio uses to find processes?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216546/android-studio-path-environment-running-a-custom-script-in-path) is similar but theres no answers for it.

Comment: It is require to set JAVA_HOME (JDK) path in system variables and ANDROID_HOME path in user variable.

Comment: Those have nothing to do with where it looks for commands called in gradle build scripts